# How to call an iOS method of an argument of a method in a Frida Trace handler?

Tags: frida

I am currently trying to log packets between some game client and server.
And I have this question.
I do this:

```
onEnter(log, args, state) {
    console.log(ObjC.Object(args[0]).$super.$ownMethods.join('\n'))
    console.log(ObjC.Object(args[0]).
        $super.setHost(ObjC.classes.NSString.stringWithUTF8String_(
            Memory.allocUtf8String('192.168.1.69'))))
}
```

And get this output:

```
- Close
- IsConnected
- IsConnecting
- portSSL
- setPortSSL:
- Open
- getCurrentPort
- server_name
- setServer_name:
- OnConnected
- getPassphraseForP12
- Open:
- addSSLProperties
- Close:ssl:
- findNewMessage
- onAllDataSended
- setLastStreamError:
- setLastStreamErrorTime:
- lastStreamError
- lastConnectionTime
- lastStreamErrorTime
- onNewMessage:
- SendMessageString:
- clearAllOutData
- setLastConnectionTime:
- stream:handleEvent:
- setHost:
- setPort:
- .cxx_destruct
- setDelegate:
- delegate
- host
- port
{'type': 'error', 'description': 'TypeError: not a function', 'stack': 'TypeError: not a function\n    at onEnter (<input>:24)\n    at call (native)\n    at invokeNativeHandler (agent.ts:308)\n    at onEnter (agent.ts:273)', 'fileName': '<input>', 'lineNumber': 24, 'columnNumber': 1}
```

As you can see, there *is* method called `setHost`, but I can't call it. Why? How do I call it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved by calling `ObjC.Object(args[0])['setHost:'](...)` - the colon.
Noticed it when looked through method names from frida-trace output.